# Svelte Kit foreach in load function to load additonal data

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

In the `+page.server.js` file I have the following code to fetch some data from an API. After the first fetch is done I need to fetch additional data for the initial page load.

`+page.server.js`

```js
import { PUBLIC_API_URL } from '$env/static/public';

/** @type {import('./$types').PageServerLoad} */
export async function load() {
    let response = await fetch(PUBLIC_API_URL.concat("/episode/recently-added"));
    let recently_added_episodes = await response.json();
    
    recently_added_episodes.forEach(async (/** @type {{ [x: string]: string; episode_id: string; }} */ episode) => {
        let response = await fetch(PUBLIC_API_URL.concat("/episode/", episode.episode_id, "/title"));
        episode.title = await response.text();        
    });

    response = await fetch(PUBLIC_API_URL.concat("/episode/upcoming"));
    let upcoming_episodes = await response.json();

    return {recently_added_episodes: recently_added_episodes, upcoming_episodes: upcoming_episodes};
}
```

`episode.title` will some times be undefined after refreshing the main page, but it is always filled if you check `recently_added_episodes` using `console.log()`. I feel like it is a timing issue that `episode.title` is some times filled and some times not.

How can I make sure all my data is loaded before the page is rendered?

I am expecting that all the data is fetched before accessing it in `+page.svelte`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Reason

So when you're using the forEach method in JS you might get this kund of behaviour. So what happens is that the loop rund without actually waiting for each request to finish. My recommendation is to not use `Array.forEach` when working with async stuff since it creates unclear code and might result in these kinds of race conditions that you're getting here.

Basically if the requests are fast in the loop they might finish before your load function does but they might not. This is why you're getting this result.

## Solutions

Easiest would be to use a normal loop like this and actually wait for each answer:

```
for (const episode of recently_added_episodes) {
    const response = await fetch(PUBLIC_API_URL.concat('/episode/', episode.episode_id, '/title'));
    episode.title = await response.text();
}
```

Problem here might be that we get a bit of a performance dip because of the code having to wait for each request though.

If that turns out to be a problem you could make the code send all the requests in the loop at once and await them with a Promise.all and Array.map before ending the load function like so:

```
await Promise.all(recently_added_episodes.map(async (episode) => {
    const response = await fetch(PUBLIC_API_URL.concat('/episode/', episode.episode_id, '/title'));
    episode.title = await response.text();
}));
```

For more information: https://gist.github.com/joeytwiddle/37d2085425c049629b80956d3c618971

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Thanks for saving my day. This solved my exact issue <3